# Python Tkinter slow response after quit

Tags: python, tkinter, key, bind, listen

When I quit and restart the mainloop a few times, maybe 4, Tkinter gets very slow at responding to keys, could even go up to 1 second, maybe I did something wrong.

```
def keypress(self, event):
    if event.char == '\r' or event.char == '\b':
        return

    self.text[len(self.text)-1] += event.char

def keyenter(self, event):
    self.tk.quit()

def listen(self):
    self.tk.bind_all('<Key>', self.keypress)
    self.tk.bind('<Return>', self.keyenter)
    self.tk.withdraw()

    self.tk.after(50, self.update)
    self.tk.mainloop()

def update(self):
    ....
    self.tk.after(50, self.update)
```

So after listening a few times, maybe 4, the response gets very slow, why is that?

Comment: Are you running using IDLE editor?
I've noticed that sometimes when I quit, a process is left running in the background.  You could check your task manager to see if there are a bunch of "pythonw.exe" instances running.

Comment: I ran your code and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please provide code that exhibits your problem.

Comment: The overall code is irrelevant, all that is relevant is there, the listen function is called about 4 times until the problem happens.

Comment: You also leave multiple tk.after events running.

Comment: Is there a way to clear all events?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the first `self.tk.after` inside `listen` to the constructor.